# How to group this query with repeated values on one column and the other column containing no repeated data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm practicing SQL and I'm trying to do a query of the best seller by section in a shop, I have this query so far:

```
select idrama, nombre, apellido, max(valortotal)
from(
select personarama.idrama, persona.nombre, persona.apellido,sum(detalle.cantidad*precio.valor) as valortotal 
    from persona,factura,precio,detalle, personarama
   where persona.idpersona=factura.idvendedor
     and personarama.idpersona=persona.idpersona
     and factura.numfactura=detalle.numfactura
      and precio.referencia=detalle.referencia
      and factura.fecha between precio.fechaini and precio.fechafin
      group by persona.idpersona, personarama.idrama, persona.nombre, persona.apellido
      order by 4 DESC
) as vendedorRama
group by idrama, nombre, apellido;
```

when I execute the query I get the sellers by section and the amount of money they have sold.

[image]

And I need to get the best seller by section, and the only way to do this, is  grouping by only idrama, but with this solution I cannot get the name and firstname of the seller. How could I group this data without losing those columns?

Comment: try inner joining the same table with this query

Comment: Solution can be found in the spanish stackoverflow site https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151771/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-agrupar-esta-consulta-de-una-columna-con-datos-repetidos-y-la-otra-s/152064#152064

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function like this:

```
select DISTINCT idrama, nombre, apellido, max(valortotal) OVER (PARTITION BY idrama) AS 'Max_of_valortotal'
    from(
    select personarama.idrama, persona.nombre, persona.apellido,sum(detalle.cantidad*precio.valor) as valortotal 
        from persona,factura,precio,detalle, personarama
       where persona.idpersona=factura.idvendedor
         and personarama.idpersona=persona.idpersona
         and factura.numfactura=detalle.numfactura
          and precio.referencia=detalle.referencia
          and factura.fecha between precio.fechaini and precio.fechafin
          group by persona.idpersona, personarama.idrama, persona.nombre, persona.apellido
          order by 4 DESC
    ) as vendedorRama
```

Comment: When i execute your query, i get the same query of the picture but the second row on max value is now 5.100, the same value of the top seller.

Comment: Can you add other columns in your PARTITION BY? that will give you desired output

Comment: getting the same result :(